# Stripping newline is being very tricky

Tags: c, printf, scanf, stdin, c-strings

It looks like scanf() is reading the previous '\n'. I'm trying to get my concatenated string on one line. How do I get rid of the '\n' at the beginning of my second string.

This is a c program.

I'm guessing I have to flush the buffer somehow BEFORE the next line is read in. But I don't know how to do this without an error.

Btw, I cannot use cin.get() or other standard cin/cout operations here. I also cannot use standard string operations, because I'm working exclusively with c-strings and strings.h, not string.

input from stdin is:

`12
 4.0
 Spot run!`

```
int main() {
    int i = 4;
    double d = 4.0;
    char s[] = "See ";

    int isum;
    int MAX_SIZE = 256;
    double dsum;
    char s2[MAX_SIZE];

    scanf("%i",&isum);
    scanf("%lf",&dsum); // Hope to clear out the newline from reading 
                        // in the double value. Or any other newline 
                        // before the next scarf(), but haven't figured
                        // how.
    scanf("%79c", s2); 

    isum += i;
    printf("%d \n",isum);

    dsum += d;
    printf("%.1f \n",dsum);

    char newchar[MAX_SIZE];
    strcpy(newchar,s);
    newchar[strcspn(newchar,"\n")]='\0';
    s2[strcspn(s2,"\n")] = 't'; //To test where newline is in second string.
    strcat(newchar,s2);
    printf("%s",newchar);

    return 0;
```

My output is:

`16 
 8.0 
 See 
 tSpot run!` //<--note the 't' in front of Spot!!!

Comment: Are you sure you are studying C++? This looks like a C program.

Comment: You're right, I'll make the correct. I've learned C++ from a bunch of old C programmers who still use c-style habits , so I didn't pick that up right away. I'll correct the tag.

Comment: "*It looks like scanf() is reading the previous '\n'. *" Did you find that surprising? If so, what did you think would read it?

Comment: I did think it surprising, I thought it would start reading the next line, not the '\n' from the previous line. How do I make it so I don't read it?

Comment: I'm asking because I don't know how to do this.

Comment: There are a lot of questions about the behaviour of `scanf()` and its relatives, which are some of the most subtle and complex functions in the standard C library. Conversion specifications such as `%lf` stop reading when the next character is not part of a number — leaving that character to be handled by the next conversion specification. Note that `%c` (along with `%[…]` scan sets and `%n`) do not skip leading white space; all other conversion specifications do skip leading white space. If you don't want the newline left over by the numeric input, use `" %79c"` to skip any white space.

Comment: Thanks for your insight Jonathan, that's certainly a nuanced answer. If you'd like, put that down as an answer please and I'll accept it.

Comment: In general, if you care about newlines, then read entire lines and parse them as string. Much much less headache.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<sup>*As requested.*</sup>

There are a lot of questions about the behaviour of [`scanf()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/scanf.html) and its relatives, which are some of the most subtle and complex functions in the standard C library. Conversion specifications such as `%lf` stop reading when the next character is not part of a number — leaving that character to be handled by the next conversion specification. Note that `%c` (along with `%[…]` scan sets and `%n`) do not skip leading white space; all other conversion specifications do skip leading white space. If you don't want the newline left over by the numeric input, use `" %79c"` to skip any white space.  The blank in the format string skips zero or more white space characters, including blanks, tabs and newlines.

As it stands, the `"%79c"` reads the newline from after the `4.0`, and the characters in '`Spot run!`' including a newline after it, and stops reading assuming that the input then reaches EOF.

You shouldn't get a newline after `See`. The `t` written by `s2[strcspn(s2,"\n")] = 't';` overwrites the first byte of `s2`, which was the newline after 4.0.

Did you realize that the line:

```
newchar[strcspn(newchar, "\n")] = '\0';
```

overwrites the null byte after the space after `See` with a null byte, which is a no-op.

A technique I frequently use is to print the input date enclosed in a suitable set of brackets, sometimes `<<…>>` and sometimes `[…]`, depending on whim or probable content.  For example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    int i = 4;
    double d = 4.0;
    char s[] = "See ";

    int isum;
    int MAX_SIZE = 256;
    double dsum;
    char s2[MAX_SIZE] = "";  // See comments.

    scanf("%i", &isum);
    scanf("%lf", &dsum);
    scanf("%79c", s2);

    printf("s2 = [%s]\n", s2);

    isum += i;
    printf("%d\n", isum);

    dsum += d;
    printf("%.1f\n", dsum);

    char newchar[MAX_SIZE];
    strcpy(newchar, s);
    newchar[strcspn(newchar, "\n")]='\0';
    s2[strcspn(s2, "\n")] = 't';
    strcat(newchar, s2);
    printf("%s", newchar);

    return 0;
}
```

As pointed out by [Cool Guy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3049655/cool-guy) in his [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36660448/stripping-newline-is-being-very-tricky/36660920#comment60914469_36660920), it is important to remember that `%c` does not add a null byte (it only needs a single character of storage); similarly, `%79c` does not add a null byte to the end.  So the initialization of `s2` to 'all bytes zero' is necessary to prevent undefined behaviour when it is concatenated to `newchar`.  Or you have to use elaborate techniques with `%n` (possibly used twice) to find out how many bytes were read into `s2` so you can null terminate it after the event.

The output from this variation is:

```
s2 = [
Spot run!
]
16
8.0
See tSpot run!
```

So there's a newline at the start and at the end of `s2` after the input.

Comment: Isn't `printf("s2 = [%s]\n", s2);` UB since `s2` isn't NUL-terminated?

Comment: @CoolGuy: `s2` is null terminated, unless `%79c` doesn't null terminate.  I seldom use `%c` with a count, so I'd have go take a look at the manual. _[…time passes…]_ POSIX says, in part: _No null byte is added._  So you're right.  I had some commentary about not being null terminated, but it was on the wrong grounds, so I removed it — not realizing/remembering that `%79c` would not null terminate either.  The fix is simple enough: `char s2[MAX_SIZE] = "";` to initialize the array to all zero bytes.  I've amended the code —— thanks.